# Use QThreads to communicate with several Hardware devices

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I wrote a C++ tool that communicate with several hardware devices (same code -> thread function, but multiple devices)

My current approach was to use the Winapi threading mechanismn `beginthreadex()` and `WaitForMultipleObjects()` (it works)

```
int vectorIndex = 0;
for(int deviceCounter=0; deviceCounter<GetNumberOfDevices(); deviceCounter++)
{                                           
    // create thread DATA object                
    testFlowVector.push_back(std::make_shared<TestFlow>(m_testResultsVector, m_logFiles));
    testFlowVector.at(vectorIndex)->SetThreadID(deviceCounter); // threadID is here the number to the device network socket


    // CREATE THREADS       
    m_threadHandle->at(deviceCounter) = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, TestExecution::ExecTestFlow, testFlowVector.at(vectorIndex).get(), 0, 0);

    vectorIndex++;
}           

// wait for all threads         
DWORD waitReturn = WaitForMultipleObjects(m_tpgmParam->GetNumberOfReader(), m_threadHandle->data(), true, m_tpgmParam->GetThreadTimeout());
```

**static thread function:**

```
unsigned int __stdcall TestExecution::ExecTestFlow(void *param)
{   
    TestFlowInterface *testFlowInterface = static_cast<TestFlowInterface*>(param);      
    testFlowInterface->run();   

    return 999;
}
```

**Thread interface:**

```
class TestFlowInterface
{
    virtual void ExecuteTestflow() = 0;

public:
    void run() { ExecuteTestflow(); } 
    virtual ~TestFlowInterface() {} 
};
```

**Testflow class:**

```
class TestFlow : public TestFlowInterface
{
public:
    TestFlow(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> testResults, std::shared_ptr<LogFiles> logFiles);    
    ~TestFlow();

    void ExecuteTestflow();
    // ...
};
```

I'm using Qt5 for the GUI, network communication and so on and want also rework my code to use QThreads based on this documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

There are 2 solutions

- subclass QThread
- use `moveToThread()` (recommended)

I tried both but I was not able to change it.

**--- EDIT: ---**

**TestFlow class**

```
class TestFlow : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestFlow(std::shared_ptr<LogFiles> logFiles, QObjects *parent=0);   
    ~TestFlow();

    void ExecuteTestflow();
    // ...

private:
    QMutex m_mutex;
    std::vector<int> m_testResults;

signals:
    void ResultReady(const std::vector<int> &result);

public slots:
    void DoWork();

};

void TestFlow::DoWork()
{
    QMutexLocker mutexLocker(m_mutex);
    ExecuteTestflow();

    emit ResultReady(m_testResults);
}
```

**TestExecution:**

```
class TestExecution : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestExecution()
    {
        m_workerThread = new QThread();
    }
    ~TestExecution();

private:
    QThread *m_workerThread;

public slots:
    void HandleTestResult(const std::vector<int> &result)
    {
        // do something with result
    }

};

void TestExecution::StartTest()
{
    for(int deviceCounter=0; deviceCounter<GetNumberOfDevices(); deviceCounter++)
    {
        TestFlow *testFlow = new TestFlow();
        testFlow->SetThreadID(deviceCounter);

        connect(testFlow, &TestFlow::ResultReady, this, &TestExecution::HandleTestResult);
        connect(m_workerThread, &QThread::started, testFlow, &TestFlow::DoWork);
        testFlow->moveToThread(m_workerThread);

        m_workerThread->start();
        m_workerThread->wait(m_tpgmParam->GetThreadTimeout());
    }
}
```

Could some one help me?

Comment: Show your attempts and tell us why it didn't work.

Comment: @thuga I added more details about my attempt!

Comment: *I tried both but I was not able to change it.* - Please explain what this means.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Look at my edit! Is the code correct? The slot HandleTestResult() will never be fired!

Comment: Is *ExecuteTestflow* getting called and does it exit, or is it in an infinite loop?

Comment: What is `m_tpgmParam->GetThreadTimeout()`? Why are you waiting for the thread? Nothing seems to tell it to quit anyway. That is blocking your event loop so your slot won't be called until it gets out of that `wait` function.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight We have to exit if the wait time of e.g. 5s exceeded. With this implementation DoWork() and HandleTestResult() will never be reached! Maybe you can give me a hint!

Comment: So you are positive that `TestFlow::DoWork` is never called? How did you check this?

Comment: *We have to exit if the wait time of e.g. 5s exceeded* - For what reason do you have to wait?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight We need the test result in the main thread, otherwise we can't continue!

Comment: @thuga Breakpoint and I see no progress in my device process window (the threads connect to the multiple device processes, do some operation and should emit if the thread finished -> HandleTestResult())

Comment: @thuga Sorry, one correction: I can reach DoWork(), but I have problems to handle the signal for HandleTestResult().

Comment: *We need the test result in the main thread* - You're already handling that by connecting `TestFlow::ResultReady` signal to `TestExecution::HandleTestResult` slot, so I still don't see why you need to wait.

Comment: btw your thread does not actually "finish" so you must be getting a timeout right? How long is your timeout set to? You will probably receive your signal after your timeout has occured since it will be queued up until the "main" thread returns to the thread queue for the next event. I.e. you are blocking yourself with this wait. `Even thought doWork() ends, your thread is still running`

Comment: @code_fodder Yes, but I have to wait, because we cannot continue in the main thread without the result. So how can I solve this issue? Thx

Comment: @leon22 A "correct" way using slots and signals is that your main thread function ends when it calls `m_workerThread->start();` then in your slot `HandleTestResult()` you continue the work of the main thread (or call a different function to do this).... So then "events" are driving your progress and your code is not waiting around blocking the event queue (i.e. event driven design). This blocking (sort of synchronous design) will be more likely to get you into dead-lock situations... just as it has done here :o

Comment: You do not want to wait for it. You want to react to it, which is what you are pretty much doing, if you just remove the `m_workerThread->wait` line. You emit `TestFlow::ResultReady` at the end of `TestFlow::DoWork`. You have a slot `TestExecution::HandleTestResult` connected to this signal. This is how you react when the work in the thread is finished. If you are going to wait for the thread to finish, then it is useless in your case. Why move the work to a new thread at all?

Comment: thx. now its clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to change the way in which QThread works as a threading util/class then don't sub-class it, use moveToThread. Here are some notes on using moveToThread():

**QThread notes:**

It is important to understand how QThreads work. The general procedure to using the QThreads is:

- Make Object to go into thread, assign no parent
- Make thread
- Move object into thead using obj->moveToThread(thread)
- Connect a signal to a slot in the object that will instatiate the object members (if required)
- Start the thread: thread->start()

Now once the object receives the signal to instantiate its members they will be
instantiated within the thread.

**Note:** if you call an object method directly from outside the thread (or from another thread) which instatiates object members, then these objects will infact be created from outside the thread, and you may get warnings saying things like:
"timers cannot be started from another thread"
i.e. member functions are not thread-safe.

```
// Good example:
MyObj myObj = new MyObj(0); // 0 = no parent
QThread* thread = new QThread;
myObj->moveToThread(thread);
QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), myObj, SLOT(run()));
thread->start();

// Bad example:
MyObj myObj = new MyObj(0); // 0 = no parent
QThread* thread = new QThread;
myObj->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
myObj->run(); //BAD - anything run() instantiates will be in 'this' thread - i.e. never call functions to this class directly once it has been moved to the other thread.
```

For your code you just need to create a class/object in which to run your thread/hardware communication code and implement the run() slot function. Then you can use the example above to set it up.

Make sure your "worker" class is a QOBject class (Qt can do this for you if you create the class under the Qt Creator wizard make sure you add inherits from QObject). You need this so that you can use slots / signals interface between your classes.

**EDIT** Since code was posted.

Remove the `m_workerThread->wait(m_tpgmParam->GetThreadTimeout());` as this is blocking the event queue and therefore your reply form the worker thread is not getting through.

You will need to move to a more event driven design since doing somthing like a "wait here until" is not great design alongside qt slots/signals (i.e. its not how you are meant to use it).

But if you did want to wait for the thread to end, then you will have to make sure that your `dowork()` function ends the thread. I think you need to use the `QThread::quit()` function to end the thread from your dowork() function.

**Link to useful thread guide**

[see here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Take a look here at how the worker thread emits the signal finished which is connected to QThread::quit() slot. This is the best way to end the thread for what you are trying to do, it will need a bit of thought from your side on the reason why you are waiting.

**Example Code**

```
signals:
    void ResultReady(const std::vector<int> &result);
    void quitThread(); // <------------- New signal

public slots:
    void DoWork();

};

void TestFlow::DoWork()
{
    QMutexLocker mutexLocker(m_mutex);
    ExecuteTestflow();

    // V------ Note this signal will NOT get processed until your wait function is finished! and it won't finish until the thread finishes (or your timeout occurs)...
    emit ResultReady(m_testResults);
    emit quitThread(); // <------------- Signal the thread can quit
}
```

-

```
void TestExecution::StartTest()
{
    for(int deviceCounter=0; deviceCounter<GetNumberOfDevices(); deviceCounter++)
    {
        TestFlow *testFlow = new TestFlow();
        testFlow->SetThreadID(deviceCounter);

        connect(testFlow, &TestFlow::ResultReady, this, &TestExecution::HandleTestResult);
        connect(m_workerThread, &QThread::started, testFlow, &TestFlow::DoWork);
        // V------------- Connect the quitThread signal to the quit slot of the thread
        //to end the thread once worker is signals it is done.
        connect(testFlow, &QThread::quitThread, m_workerThread, &QThread::quit);
        testFlow->moveToThread(m_workerThread);

        m_workerThread->start();

        /* V------------- 
           This should now get un-blocked once the thread ends since the
           quitThread signal goes directly to the thread and therefore is
           not blocked by this "wait" which IS blocking THIS thread from
           processing incoming signals. */
        m_workerThread->wait(m_tpgmParam->GetThreadTimeout());
    }
}
```