# How can I have QThread emit a heap-allocated QObject without leaking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory-leaks, signals-slots

My situation is that I have a QWidget-derived class, MyWidget, that will create a QThread-derived class (WorkerThread) to do some uninterruptible, blocking work in its run() method. The results of this are a heap-allocated instance of a QObject-derived class (DataClass) which is then received and processed by MyWidget. MyWidget is a transitory widget, though, and may be deleted while WorkerThread is still running due to user action.

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate this:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QWidget>

class DataClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // contains some complex data
};

class WorkerThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual void run() {
        DataClass *result = new DataClass;
        doSomeReallyLongUninterruptibleWork(result);
        emit workComplete(result);
    }
signals:
    void workComplete(DataClass *);
};

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void doBlockingWork() {
        WorkerThread *worker = new WorkerThread;
        connect(worker, &WorkerThread::finished, worker, &WorkerThread::deleteLater);
        connect(worker, &WorkerThread::workComplete, this, &MyWidget::processData);
        worker->start();
    }

public slots:
    void processData(DataClass *result) {
        // Do some stuff
        delete result;
        // Assuming MyWidget still exists when WorkerThread has finished, no memory has leaked
    }
};
```

Normally the correct "Qt" way to return the results of a worker thread is to have it emit a signal with its arguments being the result of its work, as illustrated above. That's fine for data that can be copied, but since the result is a pointer to a heap-allocated object, I have to be careful to make sure that memory gets freed.

And normally *that* wouldn't be a problem, because since WorkerThread has finished, I can safely pass the pointer to DataClass to MyWidget, have it process DataClass, and then free it.

The problem is that, as I said earlier, MyWidget is transitory and may be destroyed before WorkerThread is finishing. In this scenario, how can I ensure that the instance of DataClass gets freed one way or the other?

In particular, I'm looking for solutions that have some elegance to them, meaning that it takes advantage of Qt's features and preferably makes it so that WorkerThread maintains its separation from MyWidget so that WorkerThread doesn't need to know anything about it or any other class that might create it. I'm also open to ideas that improve upon the pattern that I'm already using.

Comment: John_west's answer is perfect, +1 there, but I just wanted to point out that your usage of sub-classing QThread is not its intended use. QThread is a thread controller class, you have "merged" your worker functionality with thread functionality to make a hybrid (i.e. both functions are poorly encapsulated. But the fix is easy (if you can be bothered!), you just need to remove QThread from worker class and then do somthing like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718991/use-qthreads-to-communicate-with-several-hardware-devices/35719710#35719710 in your myWidget class...

Comment: @code_fodder I had a feeling someone would comment about my subclassing of QThread. Given that my operation is blocking and I don't need to make use of Qt's event system in the thread, it makes sense and produces simpler code, and this is absolutely a way in which it is intended to be used. Here's a blog post that makes a better case for this than I can in a comment: https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html Note in particular the difference in length, complexity, and clarity using the run method.

Comment: Yeah, actually that's a good read and a good point, I won't argue against it since you can basically do what you want + I am all up for keeping things simple. For me, it does feel like you are "polluting" your worker class with thread functionality that normally it wouldn't need to know about, but I suppose you are just using it as a wrapper... anyway, I'd give you +1 on the question if I had not already done that : )

Comment: When moving QObjects between threads, remember to moveToThread them to the right thread too! Kuba Ober's answer seems to cover that. Or better, don't pass them between threads like that, as result objects. Use non-QObject class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use smart pointer (e.g., `QSharedPointer`) instead a normal pointer:

```
DataClass *result = new DataClass;
```

should be replaced with

```
QSharedPointer<DataClass> result = QSharedPointer<DataClass>(new DataClass);
```

Then, you could safely pass it somewhere and do not worry about deleting it. When it is out of the last scope where it can be used, the object will be automatically destroyed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It's important to note, that if shared pointer's ref count goes to zero in a thread other than where the QObject "lives", it gets deleted in wrong thread, which is going to cause havoc. So when using shared pointer with QObject, be very very careful about threads! If unsure, don't use it.

Comment: @hyde I don't understand why it matters which thread the QObject is deleted in. Assuming nothing else has a reference to it anymore, shouldn't it be safe to delete it in any thread?

Comment: I do see this in Qt's docs: "You must ensure that all objects created in a thread are deleted before you delete the QThread" although it seems to apply when using deleteLater(), as the thread being deleted means that DeferredDelete event will never be processed. It's unclear if QSharedPointer uses deleteLater, but I suppose it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @GuyGizmo See [destructor docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)... So I guess if objects [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) is set to 0, then there can't be events, and deletion from anywhere is safe. But it's not very clearly said in the docs, so I personally would not do it (instead, I'd look into Qt's implicitly and explicitly shared data classes).

Answer (score 2):

The worker should push the result to the main thread, to indicate that it's safe to use there (per `QObject` semantics). The result should be auto-deleted in the main thread after everyone interested has been notified of the completion of the work. It is a minimal change:

```
void run() override {
   auto result = new DataClass;
   doSomeReallyLongUninterruptibleWork(result);
   result->moveToThread(qApp->thread());   // added
   emit workComplete(result);
   QObject::connect(this, &QThread::finished, result, &QObject::deleteLater); // added
}
```

You're guaranteed that `deleteLater` will be invoked after the last handler of `workComplete` has finished in the main thread.

A single object in the main thread might wish to retain the results longer. This can be indicated by setting the parent on the result object. The object shouldn't be deleted then:

```
...
QObject::connect(this, &QThread::finished, result, [result]{
  if (!result->parent()) result->deleteLater();
});
```

If you intend that multiple objects in the main thread retain the results longer, you should be using a `QSharedPointer` in the `workComplete`'s argument, and you must never set the parent of the results: a non-null parent and a `QSharedPointer` are mutually incompatible: the former indicates a unique ownership by a parent, the latter indicates a shared ownership.

It is necessary to move the `DataClass` object to the main thread to avoid a race on `DataClass::thead()` and to allow `deleteLater` to work:

1. Worker Thread: `emit workComplete(result)`
2. Main Thread: start using `result`, `result.thread()` is the worker instance.
3. Worker Thread: finishes
4. Main Thread: `result.thread()` is now `nullptr` while the main thread is using it.

This might not be a problem, but usually indicates poor design. As soon as you start using more `QObject` features of `DataClass`, it turns the latent bug into a real bug: e.g. `deleteLater` won't work, timers won't work, etc.

Furthermore, destructing a `QObject` in any thread other than its thread is not supported. Suppose that you had your original code. The following could happen and leads to undefined behavior:

1. Worker Thread: `emit workComplete(result)`
2. Main Thread: start using `result`, `result.thread()` is the worker instance.
3. Main Thread: `delete result`. `QObject::~QObject` is invoked in `qApp->thread()` but `result->thread()` is the different, still live instance of the worker thread.

If you wish to catch such issues, add:

```
DataClass::~DataClass() {
  Q_ASSERT(thread() == nullptr || thread() == QThread::currentThread());
  ...
}
```

It's OK to destruct a threadless object, but such objects are not fully functional: you can't `deleteLater` them, their timers don't work, they don't receive events, etc.

The necessity of a parent check prior to `deleteLater` depends on whether you intend to prolong the existence of the result past the code connected to `workComplete`.

The "obvious" use of a shared pointer doesn't make it clear which thread can safely access the result iff the result isn't thread-safe. It also does nothing by itself to fix the fact that once the worker finishes, the `QObject` is half-functional as there's no event loop associated with it. I believe that your intent is that only one thread may own the result, so that its methods don't have to be thread-safe. Luckily, `QObject`'s semantics already express this clearly: the object's `thread()` is the one authorized to act on the object.

Any recipients of `workComplete` in the main thread will get to process the results before they vanish. If any object in the main thread wants to take ownership of the result, it can - by setting the parent. Otherwise, as soon the `workComplete` handlers are done, if none have claimed ownership, the result will get deleted from the main event loop.

Change the `QTimer::singleShot(1000, w.data(), [&]{ w.reset(); })` timer to 2500ms to have the widget outlive the worker thread and note the difference in behavior depending on whether it claimed ownership.

Complete example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/worker-shared-37956073
#include <QtCore>

struct DataClass : public QObject {
   DataClass() { qDebug() << __FUNCTION__; }
   ~DataClass() { qDebug() << __FUNCTION__; }
};
void doSomeReallyLongUninterruptibleWork(DataClass*) { QThread::sleep(2); }

class WorkerThread : public QThread {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   void run() override {
      auto result = new DataClass;
      doSomeReallyLongUninterruptibleWork(result);
      result->moveToThread(qApp->thread());
      emit workComplete(result);
      QObject::connect(this, &QThread::finished, result, [result]{
         if (!result->parent()) {
            qDebug() << "DataClass is unclaimed and will deleteLater";
            result->deleteLater();
         }
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void workComplete(DataClass*);
};

class MyWidget : public QObject {
   void processData(DataClass * result) {
      // Do stuff with result
      // Retain ownership (optional)
      if (true) result->setParent(this);
   }
public:
   void doBlockingWork() {
      auto worker = new WorkerThread;
      connect(worker, &WorkerThread::workComplete, this, &MyWidget::processData);
      connect(worker, &WorkerThread::finished, worker, &WorkerThread::deleteLater);
      worker->start();
   }
   ~MyWidget() { qDebug() << __FUNCTION__; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   QScopedPointer<MyWidget> w{new MyWidget};
   w->doBlockingWork();
   QTimer::singleShot(1000, w.data(), [&]{ w.reset(); });
   QTimer::singleShot(3000, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

You could also forgo the use of an explicit thread, and use `QtConcurrent::run` instead. There's no clear advantage to that, I'm showing it here just to indicate that either approach is feasible.

```
#include <QtConcurrent>

struct DataClass : public QObject {
   Q_SIGNAL void ready();
   Q_OBJECT
};

// Let's not pollute the default pool with long-running stuff
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QThreadPool, longPool)

class MyWidget : public QObject {
   void processData(DataClass * result) {
      // Do stuff with result
      // Retain ownership (optional)
      if (true) result->setParent(this);
   }
public:
   void doBlockingWork() {
      auto result = new DataClass;
      connect(result, &DataClass::ready, this, [=]{ MyWidget::processData(result); });
      result->moveToThread(nullptr);
      QtConcurrent::run(longPool, [result]{
         result->moveToThread(QThread::currentThread());
         doSomeReallyLongUninterruptibleWork(result);
         result->moveToThread(qApp->thread());
         emit result->ready();
         QTimer::singleShot(0, result, [result]{
            if (!result->parent()) result->deleteLater();
         });
      });
   }
};
```

Comment: I don't really see the benefit to this approach given it adds complexity and reduces clarity. Looking at your version it's much harder to figure out what's going on. QSharedPointer already makes the deletion of the object automatic, regardless of which threads use it. I can see using something like this method if you need to assign DataClass's parent so its memory is managed that way. But using the object's thread as a mechanism for deciding who has access seems overly complicated and error prone. Much better would be to make DataClass thread safe if multiple threads need to make use of it.

Comment: @GuyGizmo "it adds complexity and reduces clarity" We're literally talking about adding two lines to one method in your code... Given the semantics of a `QObject`, it is very clear what is meant: you're ceding the safe access to the main thread in the first line, and you're ending the life of the object in the second line. A `QSharedPointer` used with a `QObject` across threads doesn't inform you of how it can be used. It might be a tad more concise to use the shared pointer, but you're losing the self-explanatory nature of the code. Your `DataClass` is-a `QObject`: leverage it.

Comment: "Much better would be to make DataClass thread safe if multiple threads need to make use of it." That's true, but you show nothing that indicates that multiple threads make use of it *at once*: either the worker **or** the main thread does, and the `QObject` semantics are that you're free to use `obj` iff `obj->thread() == QThread::currentThread()`.

Comment: "using the object's thread as a mechanism for deciding who has access seems overly complicated and error prone" It's neither: that's how `QObject` is meant to be used - that's what its `thread` property is for! It is perhaps not clearly documented to be so, but in all cases when a `QObject`-derived class's non-threadsafe methods are used from its `thread()` and only from there, it's safe to do so.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm just of the mind that you shouldn't use a more complicated solution to a problem than you need to. In the particular use case I cared about, once the thread handed off the object it produces, the thread dies, and therefore the main thread is safe to use this object however it wants. No need to worry about transferring ownership or its thread affinity. The use of QSharedPointer means that everything is structured in a way that's very idiomatic to how Qt works: thread simply hands off result of computation to receiver.

Comment: I do agree about that not communicating whether or not things or thread-safe. It's very nice when code is intrinsically clear about that sort of thing. However, I've never encountered anyone using QObject::thread() as a means of determining which thread is allowed to work on something. As far as I know it's meant for determining which thread will receive signal / slot events for the object. I feel strongly that if you need multiple threads to access a shared resource, make it thread safe, end of story. And in the code I wrote, it's clear that only one thread is using this object at a time.